# Formulario de login de Wordpress no redirecciona cuando el usuario no es correcto

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Cuando el usuario y la contraseña son correctas, el formulario funciona bien, pero si están en blanco o son incorrectas la redirección me la hace a 'wp-admin' en vez de mostrar los errores en el formulario de "contraseña o usuario incorrecto". Cuando me envía a 'wp-admin' además se muestra el siguiente error:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'front_end_login_fail' not found or invalid function
>   name in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line
>   289

Código:

```
<?php


define('REGISTRATION_INCLUDE_URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'includes/');

function login_shortcode( $atts ) {

add_action ('init', function() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( get_option('home') );
    exit;
}

global $wpdb;

if(sanitize_text_field( $_GET['login'] ) != ''){
    $login_fail_msg=sanitize_text_field( $_GET['login'] );
}

?>

<div class="login-form">

<?php if($login_fail_msg=='failed'){?>

<div class="error" align="center"><?php _e('El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos','');?></div>

<?php } });
?> 

<div class="login-heading">

<?php _e("Formulario de login",'');?>

</div>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo get_option('home');?>/wp-login.php" id="loginform" name="loginform" >

<div class="txt">

<label><?php _e('Usuario :','');?> </label>

<input type="text" tabindex="10" size="20" value="" class="input" id="user_login" required name="log" />

</div>

<div class="txt">

<label><?php _e('Contraseña :','');?> </label>

<input type="password" tabindex="20" size="20" value="" class="input" id="user_pass" required name="pwd" />

</div>

<div class="btn">

<input type="submit" tabindex="100" value="Entrar" class="button" id="wp-submit" name="wp-submit" />

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo get_option('home');?>" name="redirect_to">

</div>

</form>

</div>

<?php

}

add_shortcode( 'login-form', 'login_shortcode' );

add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'ront_end_login_fail' ); 

function front_end_login_fail( $username ) {
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ){
        wp_redirect( $referrer . '/?login=failed' );
        exit;
    }
}

?>
```

¿Cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

fsfrs:

Parece que estás intentando llamar a la función ront_end_login_fail cuando realmente se llama (tal y como la tienes definida) front_end_login_fail.

Corrige el nombre de dónde la estás llamando e intenta ejecutar de nuevo el código.

Comment: Disculpa, fue un problema de edición en stack. No es la causa del problema @Adrian Fusco.

Comment: Edita y haz la corrección, por favor, para no traer confusiones a otros usuarios.